# req.isAuthenticated() is false after i implemented mySqlSessionStore ,hence user always fails to login even if authentication is succes

Tags: express, passport.js

I am implementing simple login application using express,passport,express-mysql-session .

When i debugged i found that user is set to req object(req.isAuthenticated() is true)  ,so i could login successfully!

Then i implemeted mysqlSessionStore to store session details  in db.

i cleared the sessions table and logged in .records after login failed:
data:

1. {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":31536000000,"expires":"2023-11-05T05:25:53.426Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{}}

2){"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":31536000000,"expires":"2023-11-05T05:26:00.122Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":2}}

3){"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":31536000000,"expires":"2023-11-05T05:26:00.138Z","httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{"message":["Please log in to view that resource"]}}

session ids are same but data is mentioned above.

When i debugged i found that user object is missing in the req object hence req.isAuthenticated() is false.
passport.authenticate() method:

[image: authenticate method]

serializeUser and deserializeUser methods:

[image: serialize and deserialize method]

index.js(took care of order app.use(session()),passport.initialize() and passport.session()

[![index.js(took care of order app.use(session()),passport.initialize() and passport.session()

at last when i redirect to secure page i check for req.isAuthenticated() which is false only after implementing mySqlSessionStore***

[image: at last when i redirect to secure page i check for req.isAuthenticated() which is false only after implementing mySqlSessionStore***]]

tried to print session when i check req.isAuthenticated() (screenshot above) .below are the logs:

1. without session store implementation

[![screenshot1][2]][2]

2. after implementing sessionStore using express-mysql-session:

[![screenshot2][3]][3]

I have tried to set the secret in app.use(cookierParser("secret"); and the order of app.use methods  in my index.js seems to be fine.

So i am confused  how the MySqlSessionStore is impacting the the regular flow of passport.serializeUser() and passport.deserializeUser().

I i tried to understand the serializeUser and deserializeUser method working but not sure whats going wrong. I am new to node js .

In separate file passport-config.js i call passport.use(new LocalStrategy)

[![passport-config][4]][4]

importing above file in index.js

[![index.js][5]][5]

```
    const express = require("express");
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser')
const session = require("express-session");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const MySQLStore=require('express-mysql-session')(session)
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const passport = require("passport");

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view-engine", "ejs");
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('./config/config.json')[env];
const { loginCheck } = require("./config/passport-config");
loginCheck(passport);

var options ={
  host:'localhost',
  port:3306,
  user:'root',
  password:'root',
  database:'logindb'
}

const oneYear=1000*60*60*24*365
const sessionStore=new MySQLStore(options)
app.use(
  session({
    key:'session_cookie_name',
    store:sessionStore,
    secret: "LoginAppSecret",
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {maxAge:oneYear,httpOnly:true}
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser("LoginAppSecret"))

app.use(flash());
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  response.locals.message = request.flash("message");
  response.locals.errors = request.flash("error");
  
  next();
});

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const port = 3000;

const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express"),
  swaggerDocument = require("./swagger/swagger");

//Routes
app.use("/", require("./router/login"));

app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));


  app.listen(port,"localhost", () => {
    console.log(" Server running!!");
  });




                          


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX0Wa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFHQd.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct32Z.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOUnE.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h9O9.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see your problem. Your program is adds new rows even though it has "session_id" and i cant see createDatabaseTable:true on your store config, and auto generated session table doesnt have created_at and updated_at colums. So you created this table manually.

- **Stop Project**
- **Delete session table**
- **Change MysqlStore options with this configs**

  ```
  const options = {
   host: 'localhost',
   ...
   database: 'logindb',
   createDatabaseTable: true
  }
  ```
- **Start Project**

After that your project will work fine